# Stopping the parent row expanding in size using Jquery datatable

Tags: jquery

I am using Jquery datatable.I have implemented Expand/Collapse row functionality. Expanding a row further result in displaying another table.When the parent row is expanded, the row contents are also expanded thus by disturbing the look and feel. Can anybody let me know how to stop that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I somehow managed with style attribute  `table-layout: fixed;`